# .htaccess blocking me from view index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this .htaccess file which loads a PHP to echo something out. But whenever I access my domain(www.domain.com) it doesn't load at all even though I made an index.html. If I access 
via domain.com/index.html, it loads the index fine. This is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}} nocache=true [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mediaserver.php?f=$1 [L]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need `DirectoryIndex` line at the top
2. You seem to have a syntax issue with your rule as you have 2 `}}`

Try this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nocache=true [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ mediaserver.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If you have other rules then post them here. Also is `domain.com/` giving you 404 or something else? Finally if you remove this .htaccess does it work?

Comment: If I remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mediaserver.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]` it works. I have 1 more rule in the htaccess but its just blocking IPs.

Comment: If you note I have made it `(.+)$ in above rule. Try that change.